# How to align equations in two column papers?

Tags: equations

I would like to write equations in a two column paper. However, if my equation is too long, the equations will not look good. Equation 1 is the right equation format. How can I change my equation to match the text format? For example, I should make my equation into two lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{generic}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}
\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE Trans on Industrial Informatics (February 2022)}
\author{\dots}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
One of the world's fashion capitals, \dots
\end{abstract}

\begin{equation}
C_m = (D_{m_1}, D_{m_2}, ..., D_{mk_m}), (m \in (1, j))\quad
\end{equation}


\begin{strip}
\begin{align*}
W_{imd} = \frac{\sigma_{md\_ind\_i3}}{\sum_{n=1}^{k_m} \sigma_{mn\_ind\_i}} ,   (d \in (0, k_m), k_m \in (k_11, k_j2), m \in (1, j), i \in (1, h33)) \label{eq:2}
\end{align*}
\end{strip}

\begin{equation}
W_{imd} = \frac{\sigma_{md\_ind\_i3}}{\sum_{n=1}^{k_m} \sigma_{mn\_ind\_i}} ,   (d \in (0, k_m), k_m \in (k_11, k_j2), m \in (1, j), i \in (1, h33)) \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
The destiny of Milan, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't use external links. Your question here is archived forever and will not make sense if the linked document changes. Make a small complete example and add to the question as a code block.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of copying the minimal essentials of your document into this posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be useful to split index definitions, if you would accept more than two lines

```latex
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{generic}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % <--- dummy text

\begin{document}
\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE Trans on Industrial Informatics (February 2022)}
\author{\dots}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\kant[10]
\end{abstract}

\kant[1][1]

\begin{equation}
C_m = (D_{m_1}, D_{m_2}, ..., D_{mk_m}), (m \in (1, j))\quad
\end{equation}

The destiny of Milan, \dots

\begin{gather}
    W_{imd} = \frac{\sigma_{md\_ind\_i3}}{\sum_{n=1}^{k_m} \sigma_{mn\_ind\_i}}, \label{eq:2} \\[6pt]
    \begin{array}{r @{\ \in\ } l}
          d & (0, k_m), \\
        k_m & (k_11, k_j2), \\
          m & (1, j), \\
          i & (1, h33)
    \end{array} \nonumber
\end{gather}

\kant[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your document loads the `amsmath` package, but it doesn't make use of the package's machinery to (a) insert line breaks, where needed, to break up a long equation across two rows and (b) define alignment points across the equations. Something like the following may be what you're looking to achieve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{generic}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} %%,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%%\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}
\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE Trans on \\
Industrial Informatics (February 2022)}
\author{\dots}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
One of the world's fashion capitals, \dots
\end{abstract}

\begin{align}
C_m &= (D_{m_1}, D_{m_2}, \dots, D_{mk_m}), \quad (m \in (1, j)) \\[1ex]
W_{imd} &= \frac{\sigma_{\mathrm{md\_ind}\_i3}}{\sum_{n=1}^{k_m} \sigma_{\mathrm{mn\_ind}\_i}} , \quad \bigl(d \in (0, k_m), \label{eq:2}\\[1ex]
&\qquad  k_m \in (k_{11}, k_{j2}),\  m \in (1, j),\ i \in (1, h33)\bigr)  \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Leave `cuted` alone: it will make reading the paper very difficult.

Load also `newtx` so the math fonts will match the text fonts. However, the `\_` command does not really produce a good result in this case.

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\_}{\text{\kern.02em\vbox{\hrule width.3em}\kern.04em}}

\begin{document}
\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE Trans on Industrial Informatics (February 2022)}
\author{\dots}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
C_m = (D_{m_1}, D_{m_2}, \dots, D_{mk_m}), (m \in (1, j))
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\hspace{0.1em}
W_{imd} = \frac{\sigma_{md\_ind\_i3}}{\sum_{n=1}^{k_m} \sigma_{mn\_ind\_i}} ,
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
\begin{aligned}[t]
(&d \in (0, k_m), k_m \in (k_{11}, k_{j2}), \\
 &m \in (1, j), i \in (1, h_{33}))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4-12]

\end{document}
```

The `\hspace` trick allows to override some strict rule about spacing in math equations.

[image]

An alternative trick is to use `split`, so the equation number would be centered, but we need to trick TeX into thinking that the main part of the equation has zero depth.

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\begin{split}
\smash[b]{W_{imd} = \frac{\sigma_{md\_ind\_i3}}{\sum_{n=1}^{k_m} \sigma_{mn\_ind\_i}}} ,
\quad
(&d \in (0, k_m), k_m \in (k_{11}, k_{j2}), \\
 &m \in (1, j), i \in (1, h_{33}))
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]